Random Forest always predicting the majority class
I'm predicting disease outcome using biological data (metabolites plus covariates age, sex and BMI). The outcome is a binary variable and moderately imbalanced (~12% positive cases). I have a relatively large number of features (~600) compared to the number of observations (n=2000).
The models I am using to predict the outcome are ridge regression, SVM and random forest (RF), all in scikit-learn. The prediction quality in all cases is unimpressive (AUC-ROC~0.6). However, RF is almost exclusively predicting the majority class, whereas ridge and SVM are a bit more balanced in their predictions.  Whilst I don't expect much improvement, I would be uncomfortable making comparisons between the models now since it seems RF has not been learned.
The main questions I am wondering are: why would this be happening with RF but not the other models I used, and how can I fix it?
What I've tried

class_weight with various weights (including balanced and balanced_subsample). Whilst sometimes there is a small improvement, in general recall is consistently below 0.05 (though often 0).
Optimising hyperparameters over the following grid led to no change in the tendency to simply predict the majority class (scoring='roc_auc'):

param_grid = {'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200, 800, 1400],
              'max_features': [50, 100, 200, 325],
              'max_depth': [10, 20, 30, 40],
              'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10, 15],
              'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4, 8]}


Since the other models were optimised with the scoring='roc_auc', I would like to keep this the same for RF for comparability. Even so, I experimented with scoring='recall' in RandomizedSearchCV, though this did not change anything.

I've tried undersampling to make the distribution of the classes more even (~60:40) and this leads to greater prediction of the minority class (recall ~ 0.3), as expected. However, I would prefer to be able to have the same effect without throwing away much of my data. I don't think oversampling makes sense for my data and would prefer not to use it.


Other points:

I'm using StratifiedGroupKFold in my nested cross-validation (both inner and outer).
The code I'm using was the same for the other models for which I did not have this issue, suggesting to me that coding errors are unlikely to be a problem.
There are no extreme or weird results in any of the variables.
I've experimented with dimensionality reduction techniques separately but have been able to reduce the number of variables much.
Age and BMI were standardized using StandardScaler; otherwise, all variables are on a similar scale.


I've since changed to using BalancedRandomForestClassifier() from imblearn and the problem has pretty much been solved.
I did not consider trying this sooner because I did not think that the imbalance in my dataset was severe enough. I now think that the imbalance combined with the noise in my dataset could have led to the issue I was seeing and may explain the improved performance when using BalancedRandomForestClassifier()

In RFs, if bootstrap is set to True (the default), each single tree is trained on a partition of the data. I do not know how this split is made by default, but I can imagine that having a lot of trees means that many trees do not see any positive examples during training. Since the average score is taken to make the final prediction, you would probably end up with a model predicting only one class
What is the training score? Are your models over- or under-fitting? This can tell you whether you need a bigger or a smaller model.
You can also use the balanced accuracy score to weigh equally each class

Thanks! I appreciate this answer! Good ideas to check and try

If you find the solution, please give feedback here or accept answer, so that other after you know what to do

changing bootstrap had no effect on what I'm observing. The training scores are only slightly higher than the test scores. Using balanced_accuracy for scoring in the search had no effect on what I'm seeing.

ok, if you need more help, you'll need to give us a minimal working example, including data
